# System.DateTime.Parse.Parse() error String was not Recognised as Valid DateTime

Tags: .net, date-format

I have a .net 4.0 app which uses a third party library which accepts an xml string as a method parameter. I do not have the source code for this library.

I've worked on a lot of projects which used this library but I've working on a new project on a new machine and it's throwing an exception when parsing an xml file containing a date in the following format:

```
2014/01/13 07:01:00
```

The internal exception states that the string was not recognised as valid dateTime. Editing the library to use ParseExact is not an option and I've tried changing the thread culture but with no success.  The xml file is correct.

Any help would be great?

Thanks!

Comment: The XML file [is not correct](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp).  Send it back, you don't want it.

Comment: @HansPassant I have no control over the date format in the xml file. Also, the same xml file is successfully parsed by the very same library on many other machines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
string strDate = "2014/01/13 07:01:00";
DateTime datDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, new string[] { "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss" },
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDate))
{
    Console.WriteLine(datDate);
}
```

Comment: Managed to get a copy of third party lib. source code and updated the xml parser to use TryParseExact.

Comment: Still unsure as to why this issue appears on this particular machine though. I've compared the XP setup to another machine and didn't spot any relevant differences.